# Binomial distribution with switching succes chances

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Suppose one has the following path in a graph:
$$x_1 \rightarrow x_2 \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow x_n,$$
where $x_i \in \{-1,1\}$.

I want to calculate
$$p(x_n = 1 \mid x_1=1) = p(x_2 \mid x_1 = 1) p(x_3 \mid x_2) \cdots p(x_n=1 \mid x_{n-1}).$$

I know that
$$p(x_i = -1) = p(x_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2},\\
(X_{i+1} \mid X_i = 1) \sim (q_{-1}, q_1),\\
(X_{i+1} \mid X_i = -1) \sim (q_1, q_{-1}),$$
where the left side of the distribution is the chance that $X_{i+1} = -1$.

The funny thing here is that this chain looks a lot like the binomial distribution. However when signs change the succes/fail distribution seems to change as well. Since if the predecessor is a $-1$ the distribution differs than when your predecessor is a $1$. Suppose we look at a sequence with $n = 5$:
$$1,-1,1,-1,1,$$
then with the above knowledge we get $\dfrac{1}{2} q_{-1}^4$, which is obviously different than when one looks at the binomial distribution.

I was wondering if there is an easy way to calculate  $p(x_n=1 \mid x_1=1)$. I tried looking at the Poisson binomial distribution like in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution

However this did not help me much further.

I did also look at the Beta-bionomial distribution which seemed a better alternative for this problem. However i don't seem to understand how to choose $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution

---

The eventual goal is to understand the behavior of tree graphs so let $G$ be a graph, an assume that each node has one incoming edge except the center node which has no incoming edges. Then the new chain will look like this:
$$X_0 \rightarrow X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow X_n,$$
where $X_0 \in \{-1,1\}$, and $X_i \in \{-1,1\}^{k_i}$ where $k_i$ is the amount of nodes with distance $k_i$ from $x_0$. Is there a way to calculate certain components like
$$P(X_n = \{1,1,\dots,1\} \mid X_0 = 1)?$$

Answer (score 3):

Under the given condition, $\{X_k\}$ is a Markov process and$$
P(X_{k + 1} = X_k) = q_1,\ P(X_{k + 1} = -X_k) = q_{-1}. \quad \forall 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n - 1
$$
Because $x_1 = 1$, then the equivalent condition for $x_n = 1$ is that there are exactly even number of indices $k \in \{1, \cdots, n - 1\}$ such that $X_{k + 1} = -X_k$. Note that for any $0 \leqslant m \leqslant \left[ \dfrac{n - 1}{2} \right]$, if a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k = 2}^n \in \{\pm 1\}^{n - 1}$ changes signs for $2m$ times, then $x_n = 1$ and$$
P(X_2 = x_2, \cdots, X_n = x_n \mid X_1 = 1) = q_{-1}^{2m} q_1^{n - 1 - 2m}.
$$
Also, there are exactly $C(n, 2m)$ sequences $\{x_k\}_{k = 2}^n \in \{\pm 1\}^{n - 1}$ that change signs for $2m$ times. Therefore,$$
P(X_n = 1 \mid X_1 = 1) = \sum_{m = 0}^{\left[ \frac{n - 1}{2} \right]} C(n, 2m) q_{-1}^{2m} q_1^{n - 1 - 2m}.
$$

Comment: what is $ C(n,2m)$ in this context? ${n} \choose {2m}$

Comment: Is this method also applicable if the last stochast is n-dimensional?

Thus that we have :

$p(X_n={1,1,-1}∣x1=1)=p(x_1=1)p(x_2∣x_1=1)p(x_3∣x_2)⋯p(x_n=1∣x_{n−1})p(x_n=1|x_{n-1})p(x_n=-1|x_{n-1})$

Comment: its like a path graph with a fork shape at the end thus instead of:
$x_1 \rightarrow x_2 \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow x_{n-1} \rightarrow x_n$ we get:
$x_1 \rightarrow x_2 \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow x_{n-1} \rightarrow x_n$ where $x_n$ is a vector with k components thus $x_n = \{x_{n1},x_{n2}, \dots , x_{nk}\}$. The reasoning behind this question is to try understanding the behaviour in tree like graphs :D

Comment: BTW your answer is great, you deserve the reputation :D

Comment: @KeesTil So you mean to generalize the question by considering $X_1,\cdots,X_n\in \{\pm1\}^k$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77450/discussion-between-kees-til-and-alex-francisco).